# libgdx - snap sprite to cursor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently trying to snap a crosshair sprite to my game's cursor using libgdx. The game is top-down view:

```
    Texture crosshair_text = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/crosshair1.png"));
    this.crosshair = new Sprite(crosshair_text, 0, 0, 429, 569);

    //...
@Override
public void render() {  

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();

    //.. sprites that scale based on camera (top-down view)

    batch.end();

    //draws 'ui' elements
    floatingBatch.begin();

    //...

    //snap to cursor
    this.crosshair.setPosition( Gdx.input.getX(), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()) );

    //transform
    this.crosshair.setScale(1/cam.zoom);

    //draw
    this.crosshair.draw(floatingBatch);

    floatingBatch.end();
}
```

Sorry if there are errors that I didn't catch, this isn't an exact copy of my code. The problem here is that 1. The sprite doesn't snap to the correct position and 2. the crosshair sprite lags behind the current position of the mouse on the screen. Can anyone give me insight on how to fix either of these two issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your position might not be correct because the screen location isn't necessarily the right location to draw onto using your `OrthographicCamera`, try using the `unproject` first. E.g:

```
Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3( Gdx.input.getX(), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()), 0); //Get the mouse-x and y like in your code
cam.unproject(mousePos); //Unproject it to get the correct camera position
this.crosshair.setPosition(mousePos.x, mousePos.y); //Set the position
```

Plus you need to make sure your floating batch is set to the projection matrix of the camera, add the following code:

```
floatingBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing a `Sprite` at the mouse position, you could change the cursor image:

```
Gdx.input.setCursorImage(cursorPixMap, hotspotX, hotspotY);
```

Where `cursorPixMap` is a `PixMap` of the new cursor image an `hotspotX` and `hotspotY` is the "origin" of the `PixMap`/cursor image. In your case it would be the center of the `crosshair`.
So basicly the `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()` return the current position of the `hotspotX` and `hotspotY`.

I suggest to read the wiki artikcle about the [cursor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Cursor-visibility-%26-catching).

Comment: I actually did manage to find this. I believe that this is technically the right solution, since using a sprite has (for me) resulted in the crosshair sprite lagging about a frame behind the mouse. Unfortunately using a pixmap seems pretty limiting... like if you want an animated cursor, etc.

Comment: @EvanDefend yea, i guess thats a bit more complicated, but it should be possible to some degree.

Comment: @SheerSt I have the same issue with the sprite lagging behind the mouse. Is there still no solution for this? - because yeah, it is pretty limiting using a pixmap. For example you have always the same sprite size regardless of the screen resolution which is a bit annoying... but I'm still forced to use the solution of Springrbua because of the lagging problem.